# Can't Access Data in EBS Volume When I Attached Volume To New Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, volume

My directory is looking like it is mounted but if I terminate the instance and mount this volume to the new instance I can not see data from the old instance. Idk maybe I am missing some parts of the mounting. here is how I mount in the new instance.

```
      'aws ec2 attach-volume --device /dev/xvdc --instance-id --volume-id   --region=us-east-1',
      'sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdc',
      'sudo mkdir /backup',
      'sudo mount /dev/xvdc /backup/'
```

Comment: `sudo mkfs -t ext4 ` - this formats your volume, doesn't it?

Comment: yes! That was the answer. Thank you so much :)